# Why is a backslash is becoming two my string?

Tags: python, string, escaping, shutil, rawstring

I want to send a text file to a network printer using Python on a Windows everything. I can't format my destination string properly. This method :

```
shutil.copy(fileName, '\\server\printer')
```

Spits out this error :

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\server\\printer'
```

Where in the world is that second backslash coming from?

I can copy files with success from the command prompt, which narrows my problem down to this `shutil.copy()` method. I've been researching strings, string representations, escape characters, and UNC paths with no luck.

Maybe we should escape those backslashes like this?

```
shutil.copy(fileName, '\\\\server\\printer')
```

Nah, maybe we should try a raw string like this?

```
shutil.copy(fileName, r'\\server\printer')
```

Nah, that doesn't work. I guess I don't know much about how the destination string moves behind the scenes or what it looks like while doing that, and I'm not really sure how to find out. Maybe I should dig into the `shutil.copy()` method? Okay lets take a look,

```
def copyfile(src, dst, *, follow_symlinks=True):
    """Copy data from src to dst.

    If follow_symlinks is not set and src is a symbolic link, a new
    symlink will be created instead of copying the file it points to.

    """
    if _samefile(src, dst):
        raise SameFileError("{!r} and {!r} are the same file".format(src, dst))

    for fn in [src, dst]:
        try:
            st = os.stat(fn)
        except OSError:
            # File most likely does not exist
            pass
        else:
            # XXX What about other special files? (sockets, devices...)
            if stat.S_ISFIFO(st.st_mode):
                raise SpecialFileError("`%s` is a named pipe" % fn)

    if not follow_symlinks and os.path.islink(src):
        os.symlink(os.readlink(src), dst)
    else:
        with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
            with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
                copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)
    return dst
```

See I don't even know where to start when looking at something like this and it seems like more of a headache than I can afford for such an innocuous error.

Comment: Why didn't using `shutil.copy(fileName, '\\\\server\\printer')` work?  I haven't used `shutil`, but my understanding of python strings tells me that should be fine.

Comment: \ is an escape character. A \ followed by an other char is used for special characters such as \n (newline) \t (tab) for a normal \ you need to escape it and use \\. For paths you may find it easier to use /.

Comment: Owen: that particular method call gets the error `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '\\\\di-shrinkrap\\satoHand'` I don't know why that doesn't work. ktzr: That doesn't explain why Owen's method call doesn't work. Using / gives a similar error.

Comment: I've since abandoned the `shutil.copy()` function in favor of running a batch file to copy the printable file over. Don't have to worry about this error anymore lol